# Break line when reach div

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem, when paragraph reach `div`, text goes behind the `div` and I can't see the text.

To be more clear, visit this site: [VivaSpa.lt/viva/](http://vivaspa.lt/viva/) and in menu bar go in these links (in menu bar), if you can't see problem zoom out 50% of the page because in 1920x1080 you can't see it (you can, but just a little). I also added picture to show problem (I marked it with yellow marker):

[image]

Comment: have you tried `text-wrap`? Also, please post your HTML and CSS code here, rather than a link to your website; if the link goes down, your post is useless.

Comment: @TylerH Yes I tried, I will edit soon, and add my codes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `padding:0 310px 0 160px` to the `body` element

(*`310px` for the right side as that is the width+distance from right of the facebook box, and `160px` for the left side as that is the width+distance from left of the menu*)

Comment: Thank you, it works, but Can you explain by how you know default pixels or it is by 800x600 ? Also do you know how to disable `position: fixed` when phone will connect to site ?

Comment: @leftas 300 pixels is the default for the facebook activity plugin. and your menu is 150 pixels.. i just show it on your css.

Comment: @leftas for the `position:fixed` on mobiles search for `media queries`

Comment: ah it was dumb question... I new to html and css things, I was programming on C# and c++ also java. Thanks for help ;)